# Android unit test caching

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, caching

What is unit test caching and how do I enable it? My understanding of unit test caching is that tests that have code that changes (source code not test code) will only rerun those tests -- which I believe is called incremental unit test caching. My goal is to use cache as much as possible to improve our CI/CD pipeline. If unit test cache works as I thought it works then it can cut build times down significantly.

What I'm finding is that when I run `./gradlew :app:testDebugUnitTest` is that it will run all the tests once and if I run that command again it will say everything is up-to-date and not run the tests. However when I run `testDebugUnitTest` from the gradle task selector in Android Studio it will always rerun the tests and it doesn't seem like any caching is applied. The latter behavior is what happens in my CI/CD environment and all the tests will rerun every time even if I'm building from an existing branch.

As far as lint caching it appears to work intermittently. It seems like if I make any changes to the source code it runs everything again instead of just lint checking the affected file.

This is what a subset of my `gradle.properties` looks like. I also have local build cache enabled in my `settings.gradle`. I am also using Android Gradle Plugin 7.2.0 which contains the updates for lint caching as well as the unit test caching (3.6.0). `includeAndroidResources = true` is in my app `build.gradle which was the source of another bug which supposedly is fixed.

```
# Enable caching for lint
org.gradle.caching=true
        
# Run kapt tasks in parallel
kapt.use.worker.api=true
        
# Improve incremental build time with compile avoidance
kapt.include.compile.classpath=false
        
# Enable databinding build caching
android.databinding.incremental=true
        
# Enable caching for unit tests
android.testConfig.useRelativePath=true
        
# Enable multi-module parallel support
org.gradle.parallel=true
        
# Enable daemon sharing
org.gradle.daemon=true
        
# Increase memory, class file space, and speed up garbage collection
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx6g -XX:MaxPermSize=4g -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Does anyone know if this is the expected behavior or if maybe I just have a wrong understanding of unit test cache?

Resources I used to try and enable caching:
`https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115873047`
`https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/caching_android_projects.html`
`https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/caching_java_projects.html`

Comment: any solution found?

Comment: It seems like unit test caching is done on a per module basis rather than code coverage. It would be nice if it was more granular but that seems like a much harder task